# Android app crashes with SIG 9

Tags: android, process, kill-process

I know, usually you would tell me to check the logs (before the crash, and see if I missed something) . . Nothing, because the app crashes no matter what, when I try to start a new activity. The only two activities that works are `SplashScreen` and `SignIn`

For the sake of trying to find out the problem to this, I did something simple

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity{
private final static String TAG = SplashScreen.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int DELAY = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, Root.class));
    finish();
}
```

and Root.class

```
public class Root extends AppCompatActivity {
private final static String TAG = Root.class.getSimpleName();
private long backPressedTime = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "super.onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.trending);
    Log.i(TAG, "setContentView");
}
```

So I set up some logs and looks like I goes to the second log.. 3rd one `setcontentView` is not displayed in console. The problem is even more weird, because no matter what class I try to start, it happens the same.

Mentions:

- checked logs, nothing there with an exception (a warning `03-13 13:52:33.302 23233-23233/com.example.codkom.shirtex W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable ...`
- worked on the app a couple of days and tested on my personal device (working without problems, even now it does) but not on any other devices..
- if does count, I use multidex, I override my `Application` class and did `Multidex.install(context);` as per documentation (said this because I had a guess that might be cause by Multidex but tested on API 21+ without multidex and it was ok(since API 21+ handle multidex on it's own)
- I have 7 activities in my project, problem occurs on 3 of them

I got to a point where I have no idea what else to do.. so that's why I came here with this question.

**Requested:**
[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cl_"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@drawable/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_hamburger_menu">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_15_dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/content_frame"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.codkom.shirtex.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <include layout="@layout/mainmenu_activity"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

In Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".application.ShirTexApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:fullBackupContent="true">
<activity android:name=".activities.Root" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
</application>
```

Comment: From the screen shot it looks that you start your app with an intent. What happens if you start it "normally" by tapping the app's icon on the device?

Comment: The problem is that I have no more info's related to this.. But for sure it happens in `onCreate()`, but not to every activity class, just on some of them. I was thinking maybe is Theme related but doesn't seem to find a connection between crashing activities..

Comment: Please do not post images when you have the text available. It makes it harder to read and search for text segments.

Comment: It was a small fragment of text, I don't think it is hard to check on it

Comment: would you like to post `R.layout.trending`

Comment: @RahulKumar edited the post with specified `layout`

Comment: do you use any ndk in your project, if yes then https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646236/1042124 might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but no.. I am not using any ndk

Comment: would you like to add the manifest entry for one of the crashed activity as well as for the `<application>`

Comment: `<activity android:name=".activities.Root" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>` there you go, edited the post again

Comment: Can you please paste the actual _logcat_ output, the one from the _logcat_ window (ALT+6 shortcut) and not from the _run_ window (that you've posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Seems, You are using vector Drawables for Images. Vector Drawables doesnot have support below 5.0. To make support vector drawables in below 5.0 and all devices follow the steps.

**Step 1:**

First you have to mention in gradle.
provide the support library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

enable Vecor Drawable Support

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
}
```

**Step 2:**

In design XML, when directly using ImageViews should use `srcCompat` instead of `src` for Vector Drawables.

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

When using it in supporting drawable of components like leftDrawable, rightDrawable of Views, you should wrap the vector in drawable.

ic_action_wrapped.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_search_vector"/>
</selector>
```

**Step 3:**
    When you're loading the vector image in runtime, you have to load the image like that.

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.ic_action_search_vector);
```

For Some Devices in Application class or your Activity.

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

In Your Case
     Based on log, Toolbar or FloatingActionButton having vector image change and check that.

Google Documenation : [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html)

Stack Overflow also having many reference for vector drawables.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, I was right about the problem.. Crash is on `setContentView()` but not on every class, just on those in which I had a `FloatingActionButton` inside activity's XML. More precisely, because of `android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"`

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan Yes, same as vector drawables.. backgroundTint also supported after 5.0. Whenever you have a problem with views. it will crash on setContentView

Comment: But my midSdkVersion is 21, shouldn't be that ok ?

Comment: Anyway, I have given you the `bounty` for this nice and detailed answer. My Problem was fixed . Thanks a lot